# Flask+uWSGI+nginx: ImportError: No module named webapp.extensions

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi

I followed the Mastering Flask tutorial book and [this DO tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-centos-7) on deploying to Digital Ocean, and have gone off the rails. I am hoping it's something simple with the wsgi.py, but have tried all I can. Here is my file structure:

```
~/
├── flaskblog
│   ├── flaskblogenv
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── manage.py
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   └── webapp
│       ├── config.py
│       ├── controllers
│       ├── extensions.py
│       ├── forms.py
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── models.py
│       ├── static
│       └── templates
└── wsgi.py
```

Here is the wsgi.py contents from another tutorial:

```
from flaskblog import webapp as application

if __name__ == "__main__":
  application.run()
```

When I run:
`uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:8000 -H ~/flaskblog/flaskblogenv  --protocol=http -w wsgi`

Here is what I get:

```
(flaskblogenv) root@flask-blog:~# uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:8000 -H ~/flaskblog/flaskblogenv  --protocol=http -w wsgi.py
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.12 (64bit) on [Sat May  7 03:35:30 2016] ***compiled with version: 4.8.4 on 05 May 2016 20:15:54
os: Linux-3.13.0-85-generic #129-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 17 20:50:15 UTC 2016
nodename: flask-blog
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /root
detected binary path: /root/flaskblog/flaskblogenv/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) ***
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your processes number limit is 3750
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 0.0.0.0:8000 fd 3
Python version: 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 18:01:27)  [GCC 4.8.2]
Set PythonHome to /root/flaskblog/flaskblogenv
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x94bce0
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 72768 bytes (71 KB) for 1 cores
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
from flaskblog import webapp as application
File "./flaskblog/webapp/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
from .models import db, mongo, User, Role, Post, Comment, Tag
File "./flaskblog/webapp/models.py", line 13, in <module>
from webapp.extensions import bcrypt
ImportError: No module named webapp.extensions
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (and the only) (pid: 23544, cores: 1)
```

Here is the top of models.py:

```
import datetime
from itsdangerous import (TimedJSONWebSignatureSerializer as Serializer,
                      BadSignature,
                      SignatureExpired
                      )

from flask import current_app
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask.ext.login import AnonymousUserMixin
from flask.ext.mongoengine import MongoEngine
from webapp.extensions import bcrypt
```

Edited to add links to tutorial.

Comment: Better follow digitalocean flask guide. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-centos-7

Comment: Yes, that's what I was following; it worked to the very end on the sample app in the tutorial, it's using the one from the book that I am having trouble with.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `from flaskblogenv.webapp.extensions import bcrypt` ?

Comment: Has this answer solved your problem? If yes, then could you please mark it as Answer?

Comment: Thanks for your help, that wasn't it though. Posted below.

Answer (score 0):

I had to call uwsgi in a different way because of the app factory. This was actually in the book I was following:

```
uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:5000 -H ~/flaskblog/flaskblogenv  --protocol=http 
--module 'create_app('project.config.ProdConfig')'
```